# Otto bus and ViewPager registering multiple times

Tags: android, android-viewpager, otto

I have application with menu drawer. One of the menu options, change main container to ViewPager. In ViewPager, I have fragment which subsribes to Otto Event Bus (in onResume() method). On first click, onResume() method in ViewPager is called, then onResume() method in fragment, so bus is registerd. But when user click once again in that option, only ViewPager's method onPause is being called, so Otto (in onPause() method, in fragment) is not being unregisterd. After that I have two registerd buses. What method is the best to solve this? Manualy call fragment's onPause() method in ViewPager's onPause()? Or there is better solution?

```
onGroupClick
onConstructor ActivitiesViewPager
view pager onResume
fragment onCreate
fragment onResume
fragment registering bus
fragment bus event

onGroupClick
onConstructor ActivitiesViewPager
view pager onPause
view pager onResume
fragment onCreate
fragment onResume
fragment registering bus
fragment bus event
fragment bus event
```

Comment: It looks you create a new fragment every time onGroupClick because in case this was the same instance registered twice, there would be an exception. You need to review the logic where you are adding fragments.

Comment: @beworker Yes, I know that - this is standard menu drawer implementation. My question was: how I can solve this?